What phenomenon is this (placebo effect?): Sick => take ineffective medicine => think you're better
When you are okay but somehow think you are sick and need medicine, doctors might prescribe you placebos. After taking the placebos, you might "feel better" => This is called "the placebo effect".
I, however, often see people experience something seemingly similar yet so different. They are actually sick, find some questionable medicine for themselves, and then think that their health has improved after taking that medicine even though their conditions are still the same.
Is there an efficient way to talk about this phenomenon? For example, my girlfriend has taken a pilates course for 3 days and now thinks her chronic back pain has been reduced significantly lol. What can I say to show her my skepticism?

Are you sure it's not ______?


Psychosomatic describes a physical illness that results at least in part from mental causes.  But I don't see why it can't also refer to recovery "from mental causes".

or "All in the mind"   But since "pain" is essentially a cognitive state (as opposed to tissue damage etc) if you think your back pain has been reduced then it has been reduced!

In psychosomatic medicine, there is always a physical cause to an illness, as well as a significant mental factor.

The "chronic back pain" might seem better due to wishful thinking. If it is better then it's not chronic.

Wouldn't this still be the placebo effect? It is a perceived beneficial effect in response to something with no real therapeutic value. It doesn't really matter if the condition is real or not, so long as the person expects an improvement and perceives there to be one. Either way, the patient feels better, but we know the treatment wasn't directly responsible.

@NuclearHoagie but pilates isn't a placebo, it's actual exercise.

@WeatherVane If there is really no link between pilates and outcome in question, then it could be considered a placebo. Pilates might be a placebo treatment for the flu, for example, since the mechanistic link there is probably quite weak. I don't know whether pilates' effect on back health is real clinical effect or folk wisdom. If pilates really does help your back, then the OP's skepticism is unwarranted in the first place - it's clear they do not believe pilates could possibly have fixed anyone's back.

Regarding my girlfriend's case, I'm not saying that her pain being reduced is surely all in her head. In fact, I think pilates will definitely help in the long run. But she's been suffering from her back pain for years, so this immediate result is rather hard to believe.

Anyway, it's not the main question. This phenomenon I'm talking about is especially common when it comes to acne treatment. There are all sorts of causes and solutions for one's acne problem. Sometimes they buy products that they think will improve their skin condition, and maybe after seeing one pimple disappear, they believe it's worked. However, nothing has changed.

All this is a matter of opinion. If they believe it worked, you can choose to not believe it but their is no word for that except to disbelieve them.

It's not a single word, but "correlation does not imply causation" encapsulates your position.

The legitimate use of placebos is in scientific studies the subjects have consented to. Any other case of selling someone a placebo and telling them it has a real effect is considered a scam; a licensed doctor doing so would be particularly despicable (not that it hasn't happened).

Glossed over is your final request of how to label GF's perception of relief a hoax, as a means of ending your relationship with one blow. "Are you sure it's not [clinical label]?" should do the trick.

Could you change that shorthand into plain English?

I suggest the Question has little to do with ELL.
Isn't the crucial point almost opposite to placebos? Are you not describing people who believe their health has improved, though since their conditions are the same, they're mistaken?
How are those who believe their health has improved, though their conditions are the same, not simply delusional?
When your friend thinks a pilates course reduced her chronic back pain, how are you measuring her error?
Why be skeptical, let alone want to show it?

"For example, my girlfriend has taken a pilates course for 3 days and now thinks her chronic back pain has been reduced significantly lol. What can I say to show her my skepticism?" - are you skeptical about the root cause being fixed, or are you skeptical about her actual perception of reality? If someone told me "no, I think you actually are still in pain", I'd feel gaslit.

I was skeptical about her problem addressed that quickly. I suffer from chronic back pain myself and I know that it's a huge, persistent problem; it doesn't go away after only 3 days doing some exercise. Back pain doesn't show up constantly. What I think happened at that exact time was my girlfriend not feeling the pain for a short while and immediately thinking it was 'reduced significantly' thanks to the exercise. I was skeptical at that time, but not anymore because the pain in fact recurred soon after. Man I wish our back pain could be treated that easily.

Placebo effect is a valid term in your example.
The term is used formally in the context of scientific research. Maybe a new cancer drug is being developed. There will be a stage at which the drug is tested, with half the patients being given the drug and the other half being given a placebo. Individual patients will not know which group they are in. This is known as a blind study, and in this context "placebo" clearly means zero treatment.
But placebo is also used in other less formal contexts. Merriam-Webster gives this definition:

Improvement in the condition of a patient that occurs in response to treatment but cannot be considered due to the specific treatment used

In this definition, there is no formal scientific element. The only requirement is a disconnection between the treatment and the improvement. Therefore in any situation where you question the efficacy of an alleged treatment, you can describe your doubts with the label placebo effect. This may or may not be the case in reality, but it is an accurate term to describe your opinion.
Merriam-Webster quotes this example from a medical journalist's article on homeopathy:

Lack of evidence: Despite numerous studies, systematic reviews and meta-analyses generally find insufficient evidence to support homeopathy's effectiveness beyond a placebo effect.

Here again, there is actual treatment, but those who reject the effectiveness of homeopathy use placebo effect to describe any apparent health benefits.

Unusually, I've had to give your post a downvote. The whole point about the placebo effect in relation to pain is that it does reduce symptoms, it does not merely appear to do so.

@Araucaria-Nothereanymore. There's no implication in this answer that the placebo effect is not "real" or that its effects are wholly imagined and unobservable. In fact, the definition cited explicitly requires an "improvement in the condition of the patient". This definition correctly indicates that a patient who doesn't get better in any measurable way is not experiencing the placebo effect.

I'm with Araucaria-Nothereanymore for the simple reason that the Question seems to have nothing to with any placebo,  but describes almost the opposite.
Either way, I don't follow how this belongs to ELL, rather than some much-more-specific technical area to do with medicine or psychology or both.

Thanks for the feedback. It helps improve answers. My thoughts: (1) This question is definitely on point. It asks for the right English term X to describe situation Y. (2) There's a difference (I think) between the medical and layman's use of placebo effect. It certainly covers a real improvement; but I suspect it also includes an imagined improvement. In other words, English usage varies depending on whether you're a believer or a skeptic. (3) If I'm wrong, then others are welcome to suggest better terms.
